# Any way to pass an image loaded from PIL to a C++ function using Boost.Python?

Tags: c++, python, boost, python-imaging-library, boost-python

I'm trying to make a wrapper to use a C++ Class in Python but I can't find a way to pass this image I already loaded in my Python program.

I could pass the path to the image and load it inside the C++ function again but that's not the solution I want.

Answer (score 0):

"that's not the solution I want."

Why not?

Anyway, the C++ will not understand the Image object. It is more likely that it does want just the raw image data. You can get that by calling the tostring() method on the image object, passing in a encoder and parameters.

But reading the file directly will be much faster.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Comment: I thought about passing the result of tostring() but then I'd have to find a way to convert it myself it seems. Doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: @lpl: "Convert"? To what? Still no answer to *why*. If you don't say why, you won't get useful answers. It's highly likely you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Lennart: I am trying to do the same. I am trying to pass the image object from python to C++. I converted the PIL object(Python) to Cimg object(C++) for passing it. I am working on a program where I need to calculate the hash value of the image pointed by the URL and then compare to existing hash values( can be millions). Reading the file from URL again will make things slower. I want to save the time of loading it again. 
lpl:were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri: You are aware that you don't need PIL to load image data from a URL, right? You can just loads the file data and hash it. Essentially, the question makes no real sense. Start a new question, and explain what you are trying to *achieve*.

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for your reply. I understand that. I need the PIL for further manipulations on the image in Python. You're right, I need to be more specific. I'll start a new question.